# Redundant basic blocks in llvm IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I was just playing around with a program and watching its IR in llvm and I noticed certain basic blocks that don't make sense to me.
My code:

```
void proc()
{
    int i, j, k, m, n, l;
    k = 119;
    for (i = 20; i < 200; i++)
    {
        for (j = 13; j < 130; j++)
        {
                l = 80;
        }
    }
}
```

Corresponding IR:

```
 store i32 119, i32* %3, align 4
  store i32 20, i32* %1, align 4
  br label %7

; <label>:7:                                      ; preds = %19, %0
  %8 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %9 = icmp slt i32 %8, 200
  br i1 %9, label %10, label %22

; <label>:10:                                     ; preds = %7
  store i32 13, i32* %2, align 4
  br label %11

; <label>:11:                                     ; preds = %15, %10
  %12 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %13 = icmp slt i32 %12, 130
  br i1 %13, label %14, label %18

; <label>:14:                                     ; preds = %11
  store i32 80, i32* %6, align 4
  br label %15

; <label>:15:                                     ; preds = %14
  %16 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %17 = add nsw i32 %16, 1
  store i32 %17, i32* %2, align 4
  br label %11

; <label>:18:                                     ; preds = %11
  br label %19

; <label>:19:                                     ; preds = %18
  %20 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %21 = add nsw i32 %20, 1
  store i32 %21, i32* %1, align 4
  br label %7

; <label>:22:                                     ; preds = %7
  ret void
```

My problem is with labels 14 and 15. It looks like label 15 has just one predecessor, 14. Given that, why can't we just merge it with label 14? I am assuming that the basic block construction is done by the algorithm mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block#Creation_algorithm).

Comment: Maybe the compiler always creates a basic block for the loop increment, so it can use that as the jump target if there's a `continue` in the loop (and it does that even when there's not because it doesn't hurt anything)? Or maybe the code just worked out more conveniently that way.

Comment: "I am assuming that the basic block construction is done by the algorithm mentioned here." That algorithm assumes that you sort existing three-address code into basic blocks, but LLVM code is always divided into basic blocks. LLVM frontends usually go from the AST to LLVM (I'm pretty sure clang does anyway), so we're talking about input that still contains loops and if statements, not jumps.

Comment: @sepp2k, "I am assuming that the basic block construction is done by the algorithm mentioned here.". By this, I meant the rules mentioned in that article regarding leaders, i.e. how splitting into basic blocks is done. Or do you mean llvm code is transformed from AST to a CFG?

Comment: I mean C code is transformed from an AST to LLVM code, which *is* a CFG. There's no such thing as LLVM code without basic blocks. So it's not like `C -> blockless LLVM-> LLVM-CFG`, it's just `C -> LLVM` and that's your CFG. So identifying basic blocks isn't a separate step, it's part of generating LLVM.

Comment: Oh, so there is not an intermediate TAC generation which is processed to generate a CFG?

Comment: Exactly, it just goes right from tree form to LLVM form, which is a CFG (at least I'm pretty sure that's the case as that's how LLVM is usually used - I haven't actually looked at clang's code, but I doubt that clang would define it's own TAC that's then translated to LLVM and there's definitely no blockless TAC form of LLVM).

Comment: You can merge BBs with `llvm::MergeBlockIntoPredecessor()` function from http://llvm.org/doxygen/BasicBlockUtils_8h.html

Comment: @arrowd My question is *why* it is generated the way it is, nothing to do with how to merge them :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is mostly a summary of what I've already speculated in my comments, except it's more detailed and no longer speculation because I've now actually dived into clang's source code to verify that is what's happening)

LLVM code is always structured into basic blocks and the types used to represent LLVM code in the API already form a control flow graph. There is no such thing as an unstructured form of LLVM without basic blocks and thus no process of converting unstructured LLVM to a CFG. Clang directly translates the C AST to LLVM. So it does not find basic blocks in unstructured three-address code, it finds the basic blocks while translating from C to LLVM in a single step. Therefore the algorithm from Wikipedia does not apply.

What's happening instead is summarized by the following heavily simplified pseudo code loosely based on [CodeGenFunction::EmitForStmt in CodeGen/CGStmt.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/6bcedd51e193e3770e9d5c81fd4f65fa3002fb72/lib/CodeGen/CGStmt.cpp#L829). This is the logic for translating a statement of the form `for(init; cond; incr) body`. For simplicity we assume that neither `cond` nor `incr` are empty and that `cond` is an expression, not a declaration.

- Create the new basic blocks: `conditionBlock`, `bodyBlock`, `incrBlock` and `exitBlock`
- append code for init to the current basic block, followed by a jump to `conditionBlock`
- append code for `cond` to `conditionBlock`, followed by `br i1 %cond, label %bodyBlock, label %exitBlock`
- Push `{break: exitBlock, continue: incrBlock}` onto the break/continue stack
- append code for `body` to `bodyBlock`, followed by a jump to `conditionBlock`
- Pop the break/continue stack
- Set `exitBlock` as the current basic block

To get the output that you expected, it would have to emit the code for `incr` into `bodyBlock` instead of having a separate block for it. But then it couldn't push `incrBlock` onto the break/continue stack. Of course that wouldn't matter in your case since your code does not contain any `continue` statements, but in the general case the compiler needs the break/continue stack to know where to jump to in case of `break`s or `continue`s.

So the compiler simply always generates these blocks and then unnecessary blocks get merged during the optimization phase.