# When does llvm compiler split basic blocks

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

When I check the ll file generated under O0 switch, I saw many single-in-single-out basic blocks along one program path. What those basic blocks do are basically branch to another basic blocks. I'm wondering why those basic blocks are needed, and what is the criteria of generating such basic blocks.

Comment: Those disappear once you enable optimizations, right? So they're not *needed*, it was just convenient for the compiler to generate them like that.

Comment: If the specific blocks you're asking about are part of a `for` loop, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255759/redundant-basic-blocks-in-llvm-ir) will be relevant to you.

Comment: What about if {if{} else{}} else{}, if I didnt remember wrong under O0 a SISO bb will show up as well.

Comment: With that code a lot of superfluous BBs will show up because all of your compound statements are empty, but I don't think that was your question. So please edit your question with the specific code and point out which basic block you're asking about.